# Detect if a (NTFS) drive is mounted or not. If not then mount it

Tags: linux, shell, mount, automounting

I want to sync an USB drive with a folder located on a NTFS partition which is not mounted at boot time. I have found a command to do that: `rsync -axu /media/USB/folder /home/user/folder`. But I have to have the NTFS drive already mounted.

How can I detect if a NTFS drive is mounted or not from a script and if is not to mount it? I use Linux (Ubuntu).

This is the little script modified (the original is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=542664)) with your help!

```
#!/bin/bash
## CONFIG SECTION
MOUNT_DRIVE=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_Hitachi_HTS5416_SB3404GRGJRKBS-part5
MOUNT_POINT=/media/Windows/
# Local folder to sync with
SYNC_LOC=/media/Windows/vasia/Disertatie/
# Device folder to sync with
SYNC_DEV=Disertatie
#
## SCRIPT SECTION
#verify if the drives are mounted
if mount | grep -q "/media/Windows/"; then
#device is mounted
echo "Windows NTFS Drive is mounted!"
else
#device is not mounted,let's mount it
mount $MOUNT_DRIVE $MOUNT_POINT
fi
# Wait for thumbdrive to settle
sleep 10
# Synchronize thumbdrive with local
rsync -axu /media/DISK_IMG/${SYNC_DEV}/ ${SYNC_LOC}/
# Synchronize local with thumbdrive
#rsync -axu ${SYNC_LOC}/ /media/disk/${SYNC_DEV}/
# Inform user that synchronization is complete.
zenity --title "Thumbdrive Sync" \
       --info --text "File synchronization        complete."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one other solution on how you can do it. You can create a file in the NTFS file system and then check if this file exists. In your case the other solutions are probably better. But if you need to check if a NFS or SMB file system is mounted it is sometimes better to check for a file because you want to be sure that it is not only mounted but as well accessible. Then you would do it like this:

```
if [ ! -f /your/mounted/fs/mount-check.txt ];
then
    echo "Here you have to put your mount command."
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to check if a particular directory is a mount point, for example (under Linux) checking in the mount point list

```
if ! </proc/mounts awk '$2 == "/mount/point" {exit(0)} END {exit(1)}'; then
  mount /mount/point
fi
```

or (portably) checking whether the path's filesystem's mount point is itself

```
if ! df -P /mount/point | grep -q '/mount/point$'; then
  mount /mount/point
fi
```

If the possible mount point may be a symbolic link, then see if that directory is on a different filesystem from its parent:

```
if df -P /mount/point/. /mount/point/.. | {
      read -r _; read -r dev1 _; read -r dev2 _
      [ "$dev1" = "$dev2" ]
    }; then
  mount /mount/point
fi
```

An alternative approach is to use an [automounter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter) to automatically mount the directory when it's accessed. For example, on Linux, you can use [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs):

- Uncomment the line in `/etc/auto.master` that reads `/misc  /etc/auto.misc`
- In `/etc/auto.misc`, add `windows_stuff -fstype=ntfs :/dev/sdz99` (replace `sdz99` by the partition you want to mount)
- Create a symbolic link `/home/user/folder` → `/misc/windows_stuff`
- Run `/etc/init.d/autofs reload` (or whatever tells `autofs` to reload its configuration on your distribution).

Answer (score 3):

Use `mountpoint` command:

```
mountpoint -q $MOUNT_POINT || mount $DEVICE_WITH_NTFS_FILESYSTEM $MOUNT_POINT
```

The latter part (after `||`) is executed only if the first part was false (i.e. the mount point did not exist).

Answer (score 2):

You can check what is mounted by issuing a plain `mount` command.  It also tells you the "source device" of each mount point.

If you use the devices in `/dev/disk/by-id` to mount your NTFS volume, then you'll have a fixed name you can check against in scripts, as opposed to the `/dev/sd*` names that can change between reboots and drive connect events.

So something like this can check for the presence of a mounted drive in `bash`:

```
if mount | grep -q "/dev/disk/by-id/$DEVICE_WITH_NTFS_FILESYSTEM"; then
 # device is mounted
 ;; # do nothing
else
 # device is not mounted, let's mount it
 mount $DEVICE_WITH_NTFS_FILESYSTEM $MOUNT_POINT
 fi
```